# jQuery cycle through links and highlight

Tags: jquery, cycle

I'm planning to build a div, filled with a series of links, similar to a tag cloud.  All of the links will be white, but I would like to cycle through them with javascript and highlight the links one at a time.  One link would change to red, stay highlighted for a few seconds, and then would turn white again and the following link would turn red.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do that with jQuery?  It seems that the cycle functionality of this post is similar, although I wouldn't want them all hidden: [Cycle Through Divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965651/cycle-through-divs)

EDIT ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

This is the solution that I eventually found that works great!  Thank you for your help!

`var toggleSlide = function(){
          $(".words a.active").removeClass()
           .next().add(".words a:first").last().addClass("active");
        }
        setInterval(toggleSlide, 3000);`

Comment: If you modify the code from the post you link to so that, instead of using `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`, you use `.css()`, then you could certainly accomplish this. Better yet, you could use `.toggleClass()`. Here is a link: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 0):

Refering the mentioned post.. you can use insted of fadeIn and fadeOut use addClass and removeClass..