# Return record of each query as I click the button

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 query records in a database table of the same user. When I do query returns and shows the most recent query of the database table. 
I want to return the 3 queries, always show the most recent query, but have a button that when clicked close the query that is showing and open the previous query and so on until no further queries. 
In this way I always have access to the information registered in each consultation about the user.

At this point I return the query as follows:

```
<a name="view2" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" href="#dataModal1" class="btn btn-primary view_data2" />EGA</a>

<div id="dataModal1" class="modal fade" style="width:1000px;">  
      <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:1000px;">  
           <div class="modal-content" style="width:1000px;">  
                <div class="modal-header" style="width:1000px;">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button> 
                     <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Estado Geral e Autonomia</strong></h4>  
                </div> 
                <div class="container"></div>       
                <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail1">  
                </div> 
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Sair</a>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div> 

$(document).on('click', '.view_data2', function() {
  var employee_id1 = $(this).attr("Id");
  if (employee_id1 != '') {
    $.ajax({
      url: "./select2",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        employee_id1: employee_id1
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#employee_detail1').html(data);
        $('#dataModal1').modal('show');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

on the select2 page I have the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST["employee_id1"]))  
{ 
    $output = '';  

    $query = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.PsicUtentes WHERE centrodb.PsicUtentes.Id = '".$_POST["employee_id1"]."'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  
    $output;  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
    {
        $output .= '
            <h4 class="modal-title">Identificação do Utente</h4>  
            <form method="post" id="insert_form2">
                <fieldset class="grupo">
                <table class="campo" cellspacing="10">
                 <tr>
                  <td>                      
                  <label>Data</label>  
                  <input type="text" id="Data1" name="Data" class="form-control" value="'.$row["Data"].'" style="width:150px;" />  
                  </td> 
                  <td>                      
                  <label>Código Utente</label>  
                  <input type="number" id="CodigoUtente1" name="CodigoUtente" value="'.$row["CodigoUtente"].'" class="form-control" style="width:100px;"/>  
                  </td>
                  <td>                        
                  <label>Nome Utente</label>  
                  <input type="text" id="Nome1" name="Nome" value="'.$row["Nome"].'" class="form-control" class="form-control" style="width:400px;"/>   
                  </td>
                  <td>  
                  <label>Data Nascimento</label>  
                  <input type="date" id="DataNasc1" name="DataNasc" value="'.$row["DataNasc"].'" class="form-control" style="width:150px;"/>   
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            </fieldset>   
            </form>                  
           ';  
    }  
    $output;  
    echo $output;  
}
```

I will show the image with the page when I have three queries:

[image]

I intended to have a button like the one surrounded in red and whenever I clicked, I closed the information of the query that is showing and opened the previous query.

**Solution I'm trying.**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$('.conteudo').hide(); 

$('.exibir').each(function(i){ 
$(this).click(function(){ 
$('.conteudo').each(function(j){ 
if(i == j) $(this).show('slow'); 
}); 
}); 
}); 
$('.ocultar').each(function(i){ 
$(this).click(function(){ 
$('.conteudo').each(function(j){ 
if(i == j) $(this).hide('slow'); 
}); 
}); 
}); 
}); 
</script> 

if(isset($_POST["employee_id1"]))  
 { 
$output = '';  

$query = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.PsicUtentes WHERE centrodb.PsicUtentes.Id = '".$_POST["employee_id1"]."'"; 
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  
      $output;  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {
      $output .= '

                <h4 class="modal-title">Identificação do Utente</h4>
<div> 
<a class="exibir" href="#">Ver</a>-- 
<a href="#" class="ocultar">Ocultar</a>
</div> 

<div class="conteudo"> 
<form method="post" id="insert_form2">
                        <fieldset class="grupo">
                        <table class="campo" cellspacing="10">
                         <tr>
                          <td>                      
                          <label>Data</label>  
                          <input type="text" id="Data1" name="Data" class="form-control" value="'.$row["Data"].'" style="width:150px;" />  
                          </td> 
                          <td>                      
                          <label>Código Utente</label>  
                          <input type="number" id="CodigoUtente1" name="CodigoUtente" value="'.$row["CodigoUtente"].'" class="form-control" style="width:100px;"/>  
                          </td>
                          <td>                        
                          <label>Nome Utente</label>  
                          <input type="text" id="Nome1" name="Nome" value="'.$row["Nome"].'" class="form-control" class="form-control" style="width:400px;"/>   
                          </td>
                          <td>  
                          <label>Data Nascimento</label>  
                          <input type="date" id="DataNasc1" name="DataNasc" value="'.$row["DataNasc"].'" class="form-control" style="width:150px;"/>   
                          </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        </fieldset>   
                        </form>    

<div>
';  
      }  
      $output;  
      echo $output;  
 }
```

That's how it works, but I still wanted to make one thing better. I see the first record, but when I see the second the first is always open and should hide when I open the second. The second record opens when I click on view and hides when I click hide. 
Also I wanted the Edit and New button, always according to the div that I open and in my project if there are two registry open the two buttons at the beginning of the project and should open as I open the div, I show in the image:

When I open the first time the:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlSkB.png)

When I see the first record:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQHnP.png)

When I see the second record:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBlmG.png)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: @tadman Ok I will update to this structure that I even use in most of my code. Can you help me with my question?

Comment: Usually "3 most recent" translates into some clause of the form `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY x DESC LIMIT 3` where `x` is some `DATETIME` column that defines when it was created.

Comment: @tadman Yes I know, but the problem is not in the query. The problem is to create the button that when clicking closes the information of the query that I am seeing and shows the information of the previous query. Show log of each query individually

Comment: @tadman I edited the question with an image to try to better explain what I need

Comment: Use `.hide()` to hide the DIV that's currently showing, and `.show()` to show the next DIV. Each time you click, it cycles to the next DIV.

Comment: @Barmar, I do not understand very well, can you put an example?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965651/cycle-through-divs. It uses a timer, but the same thing can be done with clicking.

Comment: @Barmar, That's what I needed but with a button and automatically, if you have two queries registered open both, if you have five open all five as I click. Can not put an example with button? I've been trying but I have not been able to

Comment: Show your attempt and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: @Barmar I added to the question what I'm trying

Comment: Where do you call `trocar()`? Where is `class="to_show"` in the HTML? Your code will toggle all of them, it doesn't cycle them.

Comment: @Barmar I edited the question again, because there was more code. Can not you help?

Comment: I'll help you when you post the code that tries to do what you want. I'm not going to write it for you. Posting code that does something else is not helpful.

Comment: @Barmar Okay, but I can not find examples to help me. Is there a question that goes against what I need?

Comment: I linked to a question that's similar. I couldn't find closer examples. But it shouldn't be so hard to extrapolate, if you understand the basics.

Comment: @Barmar I posted a solution according to what I intend, can help improve it according to what I mean at the end of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hi what you can do is hide your modal in your html content, and fill it with your ajax then once you have the data you can display it ,you can do it this way:

your php script:

```
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
        $action = $_POST["action"];
        switch ($action) {
            case 'SLC':
                if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
                    $id = $_POST["id"];
                    if (is_int($id)) {
                        $query = "select * from client where clientId = '$id' ";
                        $update = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
                        $response = array();
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($update)){
                        .......
                        // you need to fill the response array here with the info you 
                        //want to display and send it with json encode later

                        }

                       echo json_encode($response);
                    }
                }
                break;

        }
    }
```

Where action can be a command you want to do SLC, UPD, DEL etc and id is a parameter

then in your ajax:

```
function getInfo(id) {

   return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getInfo.php",
        data: { action: "SLC", id:id }
    })

}
```

then call it like this:

```
getInfo(id).done(function(response){
var data=JSON.parse(response);
if (data != null) {
$('#form_id').trigger("reset");
//fill your modal form using your data and display the modal after reset the form
$("#modal").show();
}
})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I did not realize how to apply it in my project. I added in the question the solution I have but it still is not how I want it